# Dist tarball URLs from NPM CouchDB mirror don't resolve

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm playing with the internals of NPM, and I wanted to see what the raw database looks like. Through a bit of poking, it seems to be documents like this: http://isaacs.iriscouch.com/registry/less/ ([isaacs.iriscouch.com seems to be the offical downstream mirror](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/75707294465/new-npm-registry-architecture)). It lists dist tarballs like this: https://aws-west-3.fullfatdb.internal.npmjs.com/registry/less/less-1.7.0.tgz, only name resolution for aws-west-3.fullfatdb.internal.npmjs.com fails.

Why aren't the URLs for the dist tarballs working, and where can I find working ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I searched again, this seems to be the recommended repository to use if you don't want packages as attachments: https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/.